# Do class attributes necessarely need to be specified in __init__ function when creating a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, init

I am fairly new to programming an to python. I am taking a class online and we are learning about creating GUIs for applications using Tkinter.
I understand that to create a new class you specify its attributes using the `__init__` builder funtion like so:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, breed, age):
        self.name = name
        slef.breed = breed
        self.age = age
```

However in an example the gave they have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Simple GUI')
        self.labelname = Label(master, text='Name')
        self.labelname.grid(row = 1, column= 1 )
        self.name = Entry(master)
...
```

I don't understand why `labelname` or `name` are not in the argument of `__init__` or declared as attributes outside the function.

Comment: Something like `self.<attribute name> = <value>` create an attribute (if it didn't exist beforehand) and assign the value to it. A previous declaration is not needed. There is an exception if `__slots__` is used but I think you don't have to care about this yet.

Comment: Every instance of `Dog` (and there are presumably going to be multiple instances) has its own individual name, breed, and age - so they need to be specified as parameters.  Every instance of `GUI` (which is going to be exactly one instance, you don't need any more than that) has exactly the same widgets, so there is no point in having parameters for them.

Comment: Python *doesn't have variable declarations*. And they aren't arguments to `__init__` because the designer of that class doesn't need those values parameterized. By default, attributes (note, you are talking about *instance* attributes, not class attributes) can be assigned to any instance at any time. There doesn't even have to be an `__init__`, so `class Foo: pass`, then `foo = Foo()`, and `foo.bar = 42`.

Comment: that being said, it is *generally good practice* to initialize attributes in `__init__`